# How to get a column value based on a column value in one single mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I am looking to accomplish these two queries into one:

```
SELECT category_uri, parent_id FROM categories where ID = 2

// the output of the above query is that category_uri is "men" and parent_id is 1, which i now will use in another query:

SELECT category_uri FROM categories where ID = 1

// the output of this is category_uri "jackets"
```

I can now say that based on ID 2, the full category uri is `men/jackets`

But instead of two queries like that, where I pass the value of parent_id to the next one, can't this be done in a simpler and more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

You can join tables using aliases

```
SELECT c1.category_uri, c2.category_uri FROM categories c1 left join categories c2 on (c1.parent_id=c2.id) where c1.id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select category_uri from categories where ID=2 
union
SELECT category_uri FROM categories where ID = (Select parent_id FROM categories where ID = 2)
```

In this way you'll get two results, men and jackets. Then you can handle as you prefer

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  C1.category_uri, C2.category_uri,
  CONCAT(C1.category_uri ,'/',C2.category_uri) AS full_category_uri
FROM 
  categories C1 
LEFT JOIN 
  categories C2 
    ON C1.parent_id=C2.id
WHERE 
  C1.id = 2;
```

---

**Result**

```
category_uri      category_uri       full_category_uri
-------------------------------------------------------------
men               jackets            men/jackets
```

> Refer [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7e93/11)